# Android/iOS: Homescreen

Tags: usability, design-patterns, android, ios

I have noticed more and more mobile apps are removing their home screen, especially iOS apps. What do you think of this? 
Personally I think sometimes an app's home screen is redundant, just a pretty page.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are referring to the Dashboard, its dead.

Now the guidelines have became:`

`Avoid navigation-only screens and instead let people get to the meat of your app right away by making content the centrepiece of your start screen.`

`Choose layouts that are visually engaging and appropriate for the data type and screen size.`

`Minimize perceived navigation effort by keeping your apps shallow.`

There are still some apps like Google Play that shows some type of Dashboard, however, they have content too instead of just links.

there's a good write up about it here:
http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2012/09/is-the-dashboard-pattern-dead-2/

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to splashscreens (and not dashboards) the short answer is: Get rid of them!

As Phuah Yee Keat wrote in the answer regarding Dashboards users want to access the content and tasks of your app as quickly as possible. So showing them a fancy screen prior to that is simply distracting. It's also an unneccessary hurdle to getting the quick result users expect from apps.

Comment: i am not referring to splashscreens. never thought about getting rid of splashscreens...